# Error when parsing an embedded .xlsx file from a .ppt using apache-poi. The supplied POIFSFileSystem does not contain a BIFF8 'Workbook' entry

Tags: java, excel, parsing, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am facing an issue when using apache poi to extract an embedded .xlsx files from a .ppt file. It would be really great if somebody could help me out.

The subject of the problem:

Problem trying to solve: Extracting a ".xlsx" file embedded inside a ".ppt".

I am currently using apache-poi.

It seems that when I try to do it using hslfSlideShow.getEmbeddedObjects(), I get the xlsx object just fine but when I try converting it to the XLSFWorkbook object using say WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream), it threw an error saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied POIFSFileSystem does not contain a BIFF8 'Workbook' entry. Is it really an excel file? Had: [OlePres000, Ole, CompObj, Package]
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getWorkbookDirEntryName(HSSFWorkbook.java:286)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:326)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(HSSFWorkbookFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:167)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:112)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:253)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:221)
```

Interestingly it is calling HSSFWorkbookFactory even though its an xlsx file.

And **no the xlsx file is not corrupted/password-protected**. I can open it just fine.

Also, it works **fine** if I try parsing the .xlsx file **without** embedding it in the .ppt.

And the parsing works fine when I embed it in a .pptx file and call methods such as xmlSlideShow.getAllEmbeddedParts() to get the embedded objects from .pptx.

Comment: Looks like the XLSX file is wrapped in an OLE2-based intermediate layer. IIRC if you read the `Package` stream you'll find the real XLSX file inside there

Comment: @Gagravarr .. I see. I had no idea. Can you tell me how to go about reading the Package stream? It would really help me

Comment: Like right now I am just doing WorkbookFactory.create(inputstream) from the HSLFObjectData inputstream which i get using hslfSlideShow.getEmbeddedObjects(). Which other package are you talking about.

Comment: I have seen that for a .pptx, i can get a list of "PackagePart" when doing xmlSlideShow.getAllEmbeddedParts(); but that only works for pptx and not ppt.

Comment: Also there is no encryption cause if i try to instantiate an EncrptionInfo object from the POIFSFileSystem of the inputstream, I get: 
no such entry: "EncryptionInfo", had: [OlePres000, Ole, CompObj, Package]

Comment: I also tried to read the HSLFObjectData inputstream using OPCPackage.open(embeddedObject.getInputStream()) and it errors out saying 
"The supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg HSSF instead of XSSF)"  
when it clearly is supposed to be a .xlsx file so it has to be XSSF

Comment: Open the OLE2 bit with just POIFS, then grab the `Package` part, get an `InputStream` off that, and feed that into `XSSFWorkbook` would be my suggestion to try

Comment: @Gagravarr .. i cannot believe this finally worked after struggling for 4 days. What I did is the following:   

get embedded objects: HSLFObjectData[] embeddedObjects = hslfSlideShow.getEmbeddedObjects();   

create POIFS from embedded object: POIFSFileSystem pfs = new POIFSFileSystem(embeddedObject.getInputStream());  

create workbook: new XSSFWorkbook(pfs.createDocumentInputStream("Package"))


Thank you so much! (They really need to update the documentation to be honest)

Comment: Not sure quite what the "best" option is here, have [asked for advice from the other developers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64269294/685641), will post an answer when/if something gets done to improve it!

Comment: Many thanks @Gagravarr!  I _think_ Apache Tika handles this automatically: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2588

Answer (score 1):

Promoting some comments and investigation to an answer...

This was a limitation in older version of Apache POI, but was fixed in July in r1880164.

For backwards-compatibility reasons, PowerPoint will often (but not always...) write embedded OOXML resources wrapped in an intermediate OLE2 layer. This has the advantage that tools/programs which expect embedded office documents to be something like a `xls` / `doc` to cope, but at the expense of another layer of wrapping.

Newer versions of Apache POI (5.0 should be the first released one with the fix in) have support in `WorkbookFactory` for receiving an OLE2 wrapper like this, pulling out the underlying `xlsx` stream and handing that off to `XSSFWorkbook`. (Older versions did this for OLE2-based password-protected `xlsx` files, but not their unencrypted cousins)

For now, if you're stuck on an affected POI version, the code you'll want is something like this (largely taken from the unit test verifying support!):

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(data.getInputStream());
if(fs.getRoot().hasEntry("Package")) {
     DocumentInputStream dis = new DocumentInputStream((DocumentEntry)fs.getRoot().getEntry("Package"));
     try (OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(dis)) {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
            handleWorkbook(wb);
            wb.close();
     }
} else {
     try (HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs)) {
            handleWorkbook(wb);
     }
}
```